# Создать отношение "Один к одному" в laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, phpstorm, laravel5

Кто может подсказать как создать связь "Один к одному" между таблицами "participants" и "users" по ключевому полю "id" ? Перерыл кучу источников и много попробовал, последний вариант попытки покажу ниже. Если кто знает как осуществить эту связь, то буду очень рад вашей помощи, спасибо!

База данных: 
[image: Используемая база данных]

Миграция "participants":

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('participants', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->bigInteger('mer_id')->unsigned();
            $table->bigInteger('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->foreign('mer_id')->references('post_id')->on('posts');
        });
    }
```

Миграция "users":

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

В модели "User":

```
  public function participants()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Participant', 'user_id', 'id');
    }
```

В модели "Participant":

```
  public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id', 'id');
    }
```

Спасибо!

Comment: return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id', 'id');
Почему user_id? Просто id.

Comment: Можете удалить два параметра после классов в функциях hasOne/belongsTo так как они будут поставлены автоматически на нужные вам.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov, То есть оставить только " 'App\User' " ?

Comment: @RomanBush, и этого будет достаточно для организации связи ?

Comment: @Никита Филиппов измени в миграции столбцы ID на increments('id');
от этого тоже бывает иногда ошибки в связи

Comment: Вам надо понять/разобраться, что эта связь из себя представляет. В двух словах - у каждой таблицы есть уникальный айди. И Вы из другой таблицы устраиваете связь с этим уникальным айди. Для этого вам надо во второй таблице завести поле, в котором и будет храниться айди из первой таблицы. И чтобы ларавелька об этом знала, ей надо сказать: это новое поле принадлежит той таблице. По английски это будет: $this->belongsTo. А в изначальной таблице ларавельке, чтобы она была в курсе, надо сказать - у этого поля есть есть одна связь с другой таблицей. По английски будет: $this->hasOne. Дальше сами.

Comment: И хорошо бы добавить на ключи `onDelete()`. Ну и если User hasOne App\Participant то не надо именовать метод множественным числом

Comment: @RomanBush, спасибо!

Comment: @InDevX, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Миграция "participants":

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('participants', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        });
    }
```

Миграция "users":

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

В модели "User":

```
public function participant()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Participant::class);
    }
```

В модели "Participant":

```
public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
```

Первой - миграция юзера, второй - вторая таблица